# Will identity matrix necessarily appear in powers of any permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having nothing better to do, I tried multiplying different (but mostly small) permutation matrices with themselves, and so far at some point I'd always run into an identity matrix.

Was I just "lucky"? Or is there any reason for this (given this indeed bound to happen)?

Comment: If you take powers of a permutation matrix, you will eventually get the identity matrix back. Permutation matrices are invertible and there are only finitely many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you weren't lucky. Permutation matrixes are an example of a [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) on $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Being a group, every permutation can be multiplied with another permutation to find the identity application - in our case, the identity matrix. If you multiply two different permutations, thanks to the group structure their product is still a permutation, so you can find its *inverse*.

Comment: Would it follow from this that any other permutation matrix is obtainable by continued multiplication of one permutation matrix with itself?

Comment: When $n >2,$ the symmetric group of degree $n$ is not cyclic, so it is not true that all permutation matrices occur as powers of a single permutation matrix.

Comment: Thanks, @GeoffRobinson, I might be too dense... but why being able to find an inverse warrants that I will eventually arrive at identity matrix?

Comment: Geoff is right. You cannot be ensured that one permutation matrix can generate the whole set of permutations. However, you are given that: (1) multiplicating a permutation matrix by itself for a certain number of times results in the identity matrix, and that number is the *order* of the permutation; (2) that combining an arbitrary number of permutations in that set gives a permutation that is still in that set.

Comment: It is radicated in the definition of *inverse* itself. The identity matrix is a *unit* of the permutation matrixes' group, so for every permutation matrix there exists another matrix that multiplied by, gives you the identity.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother. But why am I guaranteed to obtain the inverse of the matrix by multiplying it with itself?

Comment: The reason is that you are taking powers of an element in a finite group, so there are only finitely many different powers available. If you start $g,g^{2}, \ldots$, you eventually must at some point get $g^{j} =g^{i}$ for some $j >i.$ Then $g^{j-i}$ is the identity.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson oooh, ok, I see now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation in $S_n$ and $P_\sigma$ the associated permutation matrix, i.e. the matrix that has a $1$ at row $i$ and column $j$ if and only if $j = \sigma(i)$ and a zero everywhere else. You can show that 
$$
P_\sigma\cdot P_\pi = P_{\sigma\circ\pi},
$$
for all permutations $\sigma,\pi$. This implies that if $\sigma$ has finite order, so does $P_\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry, I need a little help with this. Can you elaborate why having finite order helps, please?

Comment: @wvxvw: If $\sigma^n=$id, the identity permutation what is $(P_\sigma)^n$? Use the formula that I gave you for multiplying permutation matrices.